# Problems with reproducing the same HMAC MD5 on Java and C

Tags: java, c, character-encoding, md5, hmac

I am currently stumped on recreating an HMAC MD5 hash generated by a Java program on C. Any help, suggestions, correction and recommendation would be greatly appreciated.
The Java program creates the HMAC MD5 string (encoded to a base 16 HEX string which is 32 characters long) using UTF16LE and MAC; what I need is to recreate the same result on C program.

I am using the RSA source for MD5 and the HMAC-MD5 code is from RFC 2104 (http://www.koders.com/c/fidBA892645B9DFAD21A2B5ED526824968A1204C781.aspx)

I have "simulated" UTF16LE on the C implementation by padding every even byte with 0s. The Hex/Int representation seem to be consistent on both ends when I do this; but is this the correct way to do this? I figured this would be the best way because the HMAC-MD5 function call only allows for a byte array (no such thing as a double byte array call in the RFC2104 implementation but that's irrelevant).

When I run the string to be HMAC'd through - you naturally get "garbage". Now my problem is that not even the "garbage" is consistent across the systems (excluding the fact that perhaps the base 16 encoding could be inconsistent). What I mean by this is "�����ԙ���," might be the result from Java HMAC-MD5 but C might give "v ����?��!��{�  " (Just an example, not actual data).

I have 2 things I would like to confirm:

1. Did padding every even byte with 0 mess up the HMAC-MD5 algorithms? (either because it would come across a null immediately after the first byte or whatever)
2. Is the fact that I see different "garbage" because C and Java are using different character encodings? (same machine running Ubuntu)

I am going to read through the HMAC-MD5 and MD5 code to see how they treat the byte array going in (whether or not the null even bytes is causing a problem). I am also having a hard time writing a proper encoding function on the C side to convert the resultant string into a 32 character hex string. Any input/help would be greatly appreciated.

Update (Feb 3rd): Would passing signed/unsigned byte array alter the output of HMAC-MD5? The Java implementation takes a byte array (which is SIGNED); but the C implementation takes an UNSIGNED byte array. I think this might also be a factor in producing different results. If this does affect the final output; what can I really do? Would I pass a SIGNED byte array in C (the method takes an unsigned byte array) or would I cast the SIGNED byte array as unsigned?

Thanks!
Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the RSA implementation. After I switched to OpenSSL all my problems were resolved. RSA implementation did not take into consideration all the necessary details of cross platform support (including 32bit/64bit processors).

Always use OpenSSL because they have already resolved all the cross platform issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably due to your naive creation of the UTF-16 string.   Any character greater than 0x7F ([see unicode explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)) needs to be expanded into the UTF encoding scheme.

I would work on first getting the same byte string between the C and Java implementation as that is probably where your problem lies -- so I would agree with your assumption (1)

Have you tried to calculate the MD5 without padding the C-string, but rather just converting it to UTF -- you can use iconv to make experiments with the encoding.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but if a single bit is different between the 2 input (into the MD5 algorithm), the result would be different. Since the MAC is updated with "some string".getByte("UTF16-LE"); wouldn't I have to create the same byte array in C? 

I will try to do this without attempting to recreate a UTF-16 string. Thanks for you response!

Comment: You are not wrong, one bit difference should generate a different output.   What is not clear to me is if the Java UTF16 implementtation is only for internal purposes, in which case the zero padding would be ignored in the Java MD5 implementation -- since the MD5 sum should be of the external representation.   
MD5 as a concept only work if it is language independent, hence writing the data out to a external file and getting an external program (such as md5sum on linux) to agree would be the way to go -- and then make sure that you can generate exactly that from both Java and C.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently writing a set of tests to see at which point the data across the 2 platforms become inconsistent. Thanks for all your advice. Hopefully I can post a reasonable solution and explanation soon.

Comment: Just an update:
UTF8/UTF16LE passed into just the (JAVA) MD5 function does make a difference in the resultant string. It looks like my initial idea to pad the input string (in C) with 0 every even bytes is correct. When I examine the data out of a file I have written the bytes to, I do see every even bytes to be padded by 0s. I think the next step I will take is to go back and examine the C MD5 implementation.

Example:
getBytes(UTF8):
50 44 50 51 52 51
getBytes(UTF16LE):
50 0 44 0 50 0 51 0 52 0 51 0

Edit: Tried to format this to be more readable but failed...